# Parabolic microphone design

Tags: pressure, acoustics, reflection, resonance

How are the specifications of a parabolic microphone dish determined? Attempting to design a collector for the Avisoft Polaroid/CMPA microphone. Interested in 45kHz - 55kHz ultrasonic. Would like approximately 10° "field of view" for directionality. Needs to be barrel/cone style collector rather than large dish (due to wind loading). Is it possible to model the response of different designs or will trial and error be required? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is an engineering problem, so it doesn't really meet the requirements of the site. As for the answer... to be honest, I would use half a dozen of microphones, or more, and solve the problem with digital signal processing, which, today, is both cheap and far superior to physical methods. I can't quite see why wind loading should be a problem for a small dish, though. The wavelength here is like 7mm and the dish size for 10 degrees of directionality would probably be hardly larger than a hand or two.

Comment: If your question is closed, don't worry, only simply re-ask it on http://engineering.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Sorry, my apologies for this. Didn't realise I was off topic. Thanks for those who provided answers already. I will try reposting with more detail in the engineering exchange. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Expanding @CuriousOne's comment into an answer:

With a parabolic dish, you control directionality with the size of the dish. For a given wavelength, your first null in the response happens at an angle

$$\alpha = \frac{1.22 \lambda}{d}$$

For 50 kHz ultrasound, the wavelength at STP is approximately 7 mm; we find

$$d = \frac{1.22 c / f}{10*\pi/180} = 4.8~\rm{cm}$$

I can't imagine you run into problems with wind loading at that size.

Comment: Thank you Floris. The wind loading concern is because this will be mounted to the roof of a 4WD vehicle that will need to travel at highway speeds in between locations.

Comment: It's much smaller than your rear view mirror which survives. By the way - I hope you know ultrasound is attenuated quite strongly in air; what range are you hoping to achieve? What is the source of the sound? Bats? You might be interested in http://www.wildlife-sound.org/journal/2007/bats/

Comment: Hi Floris, thanks for the link, there is some interesting content in there. For this particular application we are hoping to listen for ultrasonic emission from high voltage overhead lines. All of the existing systems for this application seem to heterodyne the signal before any processing takes place. We are planning to capture the raw signal for processing. The bat recorders seem to be the simplest off the shelf solution for capturing airborne ultrasound.